# How to catch an error of promise in OrientDB?

Tags: promise, try-catch, orientdb, es6-promise

```
UPDATE: this is not a problem of code. Code works as it should.

I've restarted OrientDB server for few times and then it works as it should.

So, the problem was in OrientDB server, not the code.

Seems like there is no timeout for promise result. So, when I was calling `db.class.get` the promise was stuck without invocation of  `then` or `catch`.
```

> My problem arose because of a rare coincidence. Code works properly.

For instance, why I cannot get a callback to catch an error when trying to get class?

Look at this example - http://orientdb.com/docs/master/OrientJS-Class-Classes.html#getting-classes

Now, when I do this:

```
db.class.get('Player')
.then(
    function(player){
        console.log('Retrieved class: ' + player.name);
    }
)
.catch(
    function(err){
        console.log('Getting class Player error:',err)
    }
);
```

nothing was logged actually. No errors, no success.

This is not only 'fake' promise I've found.
I think OrientDB's tutorial is so limited.

So, how can I catch an error when getting class?

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it works for me, I can get the class if exists and I get the error if it doesn't exists. So, what's the problem? Thx in advance

Comment: It's very strange. When my db is `ok` the `then` function works. But when db is not `ok` I have nothing in my console - `catch` function not invoked at all.

Also I have error when I trying to use `then` on `server.use` as in the tutorial:

TypeError: server.use(...).then is not a function

So, I don't use `then`. Can we talk privately?

Comment: What do you mean with db not ok?

Comment: Please, let's talk here - http://temp.mexy.pro/#Kmt2OniG8p

(no registration)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried you code and, in my case, it works!

At the beginning, I did not create the class "Player" and, in fact, your code has given me the following output:

```
Getting class Player error: { OrientDB.RequestError: No such class: Player
    at Db.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\orientjs\lib\db\class\index.js:296:64)
    at Db.tryCatcher (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:577:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:128:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Alberto Brunetti\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:574:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)
  name: 'OrientDB.RequestError',
  message: 'No such class: Player',
  data: {} }
```

In this code you can see the error message that you expect (first line).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've restarted OrientDB server for few times and then it works as it should be.

So, the problem was in OrientDB server, not my code.

Seems like there is no timeout for promise result. So, when I was calling `db.class.get` the promise was stuck without invocation of  `then` or `catch`.